# Folding and Unfolding animation XML in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-animation, fold

I have been trying to do **fold and unfold animation** through XML in android.
I did some research and development for the same but not able to find a proper solution for this.

I came to know about some library like [FoldableLayout](https://github.com/alexvasilkov/FoldableLayout), [Ramotion Folding Cell](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android) etc, but I want to animate my view using XML animation.

If anyone can provide a proper guide for the same with Java code that will also work.

So, if anyone can help me with this, it's highly appreciable.

Comment: It might help you [see](https://www.azoft.com/blog/paper-folding-animation-android/)

Comment: @Sniffer I will try this and let you know, but if you can help with XML that will be great.